# multidimensional string c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm writing a function that has a 2D array of strings as input parameter. I initialized the string, passed it to the function but when I tried to print the array nothing happened. It says that the length of the array is 0. All my functions are stored in a header file. Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int c,i,j,fx,fy;
int color,fields,rows,anim,speed;
string opt[5][50];
string popt[5][50]={
    {"caption","asdf","safd","asf"},
    {"caption1","dsafa","asdf","asdf"},
    {"caption2","asdf","asdf","asdfas"},
    {"caption3","sadfa","asdfs","fasdfa"}};

void ini(int focus_text_color, int n_fields,int n_rows, string options[][50], bool animation=false, int animation_speed=10)
{
    color=focus_text_color;
    fields=n_fields;
    for(i=1;i<fields+1;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<rows+1;j++)
        {
            opt[i][j]=options[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int drawh()
{
    system("cls");
    for(i=0;i<fields;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<rows;j++)
        {
            cout<<opt[i][j]<<setw(opt[i+1][j].length()+5);
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}

void main()
{
    ini(LIGHTRED,4,4,popt);
    drawh();
}
```

NOTE: This is a part of the code so I haven't tested it, and sorry for my bad English :D

Comment: Why are you doing `for (i=1;i<fields+1;i++)` instead of `for (i=0;i<fields;i++)`?

Comment: -1: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?  Or adding `printf`/`cout` trace statements to find out the values of variables, or how many times it iterates through loops, etc.?

Comment: And why does your initializer not match the dimensions of your array?

Comment: @Oli 1. Because I need to print out element 0 as element 1 and i was to lazy to think of another way
2. yes i've tried opt[2][2].length() just for example and it printed out 0

Comment: This is a horribly confusing, error-prone approach!  You now have to consider your loop indices in all your code (it's already caused you to make one mistake - you're not copying element 0).  The simplest approach is to maintain "natural" indexing for all your code, except the special case where you need to print things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you don't get any output is that you don't initialize the global variable `rows`, so it stays at 0. Your `init` function should be:

```
void ini(int focus_text_color, int n_fields,int n_rows, string options[][50], bool animation=false, int animation_speed=10)
{
    color=focus_text_color;
    fields=n_fields;
    rows = n_rows;   //-- ADDED LINE
 ....
```

Comment: @Martin: Running your code in a debugger would have helped you spot this problem very quickly!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @Oli's comments. To make it simpler, you can pass an array by reference. See below example:

```
template<unsigned int ROW, unsigned int COL>
void ini (string (&s)[ROW][COL])  // psuedo code for 'ini'; put extra params to enhance
{
  ini(s, ROW, COL);
}
```

Now, `template ini()` provides a wrapper to actual `ini()` which calculates the row/column of an array at compile time. Usage is very simple:

```
string s[10][5];
ini(s); // calls ini(s,10,5);
```

Your loop should start from dimension `0` and not `1` for copying. Check my approach and modify your code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
    s1[i][j] = s2[i][j];
```

Also there are many problems in your code due to **passing wrong dimensions** (e.g. passing `4` as dimension while calling `ini()`, when it should be 5).

Comment: I thought of using this method but since I'm a newbie in C++ I try to stay away from advanced stuff :)

Comment: @Martin, `template` are little complex at first sight, but not **advance** today's time. Learning them will let you avoid such errors and will make you an **oldbie** ! :)